# How to get X unique records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get 10 records from a table with max 2 same user records.

A mysql table has messages from users. I want to get unique user messages, which is easy if I just wanted a single unique message, I could use `distinct` to get it. But I want 2 unique user messages.

The table below shows the original data.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | message                                     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 111     | this is message A from user 1               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 111     | this is message B from user 1               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 111     | this is message C from user 1               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 222     | this is message A from user 2               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 222     | this is message B from user 2               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 6  | 222     | this is message C from user 2               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 7  | 333     | this is message A from user 3               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 8  | 333     | this is message B from user 3               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 9  | 333     | this is message C from user 3               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
... so on ...
```

Now I need a query which can bring 2 results of each user, something like this below, with max 10 records:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | message                                     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 111     | this is message A from user 1               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 111     | this is message B from user 1               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 4  | 222     | this is message A from user 2               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 222     | this is message B from user 2               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 7  | 333     | this is message A from user 3               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 8  | 333     | this is message B from user 3               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
... so on ...
```

**EDIT:**

Using a query like this to get records grouped by `user_id` can bring only single records:

```
select max(id) as id, user_id, max(message) as message from user_messages group by user_id
```

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
| id | user_id | message                                     | 
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 111     | this is message B from user 1               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 5  | 222     | this is message B from user 2               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 8  | 333     | this is message B from user 3               |
--------------------------------------------------------------
... so on ...
```

But I cannot find a way to get 2 sets of records for each user.

**EDIT2:**

Using a programming language workaround, we can do it something like this:

```
- we need 10 records total
- we need 2 records max per user
- we can run a loop => 10 / 2 = 5 times
- each time we get a distinct user record
- each next time we append `id not in` to the query to avoid already loaded records
```

Something like:

```
$data = [];
$ids = [0]; // keep a value in it so that first query does not give error
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
  $res = mysql_query("select max(id) as id, user_id from user_messages where id not in (".implode(',', $ids).") group by user_id");
  while ( ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) ) {
    $ids[] = $row['id'];
    $data[] = $row;
  }
}
```

But this is not the best solution as it involves code and not pure sql.

Comment: Actually I cannot think of any solution. I know if I wanted a single distinct user record, I can get it, but for more than one distinct records, I dont know how to do it or if even it is possible by query. That is the reason I posted the question.

Comment: Then post what query have you tried so far, what is the current result you are getting, what have you researched

Comment: Is there any column that would suggest an order to the rows? Timestamp? Do you want the most recent rows for each user? First two? What are the criteria for selecting which two rows to return?

Comment: There is no criteria for that, any 2 rows can be selected. If it matters, we can sort by id field, but its not a requirement.

Comment: I was thinking what if you add another column that get count of each group and 2 of each then it will work for you.

Comment: @Megh can you please elaborate. BTW, adding another column is not a better idea as it will disturb the data. I was hoping if there is some sort of sql join + group by trick that can achieve this?

Comment: Found another solution by coding: 1) Loop by distinct user_id 2) inner loop to get data of only that user_id with limit = 2 and add the data to an output array outside of the outer loop. This will also get 2 each records of unique user_id's

Comment: Note that this is just about the most frequently asked question under these tags

Comment: please go thru this post this will let give you better idea

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

but still if you need my help then let me know I will create sample query for you.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+, you would use `row_number()`:

```
select um.*
from (select um.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id order by id) as seqnum
      from user_messages um
     ) um
where seqnum <= 2;
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select um.*
from user_messages um
where um.id <= any (select um2.id
                    from user_messages um2
                    where um2.user_id = um.user_id
                    order by um2.id
                    limit 2
                   );
```

The `any`, by the way, handles the case when there are fewer than two messages for a user.